# Java Swing - Display img in frame

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw images but I want to show it in a frame when all the img will be draw. My current code:

```
public class TestURLImage3 extends JFrame {

    private static ArrayList<BusStop2> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> positionTilesAndURLPathsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, BufferedImage> imgCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestURLImage3();
    }
    TestURLImage3(){
        setUndecorated(false);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setSize(Config.xSize, Config.ySize);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getTiles(51.407,16.198);
        getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
    }
    public void paint ( Graphics g ) {
        super.paint(g);
        getPaint(g);
    }
    private static void getPaint(Graphics g){
        for(PositionTilesAndURLPaths pos : getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list)){
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getImgFromPath(pos.getPath()));
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            g.drawImage(img,Config.xSize/2-pos.getX()-Config.imgSize/2 ,(Config.ySize/2)- pos.getY()-Config.imgSize/2, Config.imgSize, Config.imgSize, null);       
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get image by geographical coordinates 
     * @param lat
     * @param lon
     * @return
     */
//  private String getFirstImage(double lat, double lon ){
//      return new String(TestURLImage.getImg(lat, lon, Config.mapZoom)); 
//    }

    /**
     * Method use to get image from path 
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    private static BufferedImage getImgFromPath(String path){
        if(imgCache.get(path) != null){
            return imgCache.get(path);
        }
        else{
            URL url = null;
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(path);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imgCache.put(path, image);
            return image;
        }

    }
    /**
     * Method use to get count of image what we need 
     * @return
     */
    private static int[] getCountImage(){
        int xImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Config.xSize/256);
        int yImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Config.ySize/256);
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get count of tiles
     * @return
     */
    private static int[] countImage(){
        int[] imageCount = getCountImage();
        int xImageCount = imageCount[0];
        int yImageCount = imageCount[1];
        if(xImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            xImageCount = xImageCount + 2;
        }
        if(yImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            yImageCount = yImageCount + 2;
        }
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get tiles 
     * @param lat
     * @param lon
     * @return
     */
    private static  ArrayList<BusStop2> getTiles(double lat, double lon ){
        int [] numberTile = TestURLImage.getMapByGeographicalCoordinates(lat, lon, Config.mapZoom);
        int a1 = 1;
        int a2 = 1;
        int a3 = 1;
        int a4 = 1;
        int [] countImage = countImage();
        int []x = new int [countImage[0]];
        int []y = new int [countImage[1]];
        x[0] = numberTile[0];
        y[0] = numberTile[1];
          for (int i = 1; i<x.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]+(a1);
                  a1++;
              }
              else{
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]-(a2);
                  a2++;
              }
          }

          for (int i = 1; i<y.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]+(a3);
                  a3++;
              }
              else{
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]-(a4);
                  a4++;
              }
          }

          for(int i = 0 ; i<x.length ; i++){
              for (int j = 0 ;j<y.length ; j++ ){
                  list.add(new BusStop2(x[i], y[j], x[0] - x[i], y[0]-y[j]));           
              }
          }
        return list;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> getImgPositionAndURLsPath(ArrayList<BusStop2> list){

        for(BusStop2 bus : list){
            positionTilesAndURLPathsList.add(new PositionTilesAndURLPaths(256*bus.getX(), 256*bus.getY(), Config.mapPath + "/" + bus.getA() + "/" + bus.getB() + ".png"));
        }
        return positionTilesAndURLPathsList;

    }
}
```

I see how one img will be add and another ...
So I do it this :

```
public class TestURLImage2 {
    int result[];
    private static ArrayList<BusStop2> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> positionTilesAndURLPathsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, BufferedImage> imgCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestURLImage2();
        getTiles(51.407,16.198);
        getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list);
    }

    public TestURLImage2() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setSize(Config.xSize, Config.ySize);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    f.setSize(Config.xSize, Config.ySize);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.setLayout(null);
                    getTiles(51.407,16.198);
                    for(PositionTilesAndURLPaths pos : getImgPositionAndURLsPath(list)){
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImgFromPath(pos.getPath())));
                        label.setBounds(Config.xSize/2-pos.getX()-Config.imgSize/2 ,(Config.ySize/2)- pos.getY()-Config.imgSize/2, Config.imgSize, Config.imgSize);
                        f.getContentPane().add(label);
                    }
                    System.out.println(imgCache.size());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Method use to get image from path 
     * @param path
     * @return
     */
    private BufferedImage getImgFromPath(String path){
        if(imgCache.get(path) != null){
            return imgCache.get(path);
        }
        else{
            URL url = null;
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(path);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imgCache.put(path, image);
            return image;
        }

    }
    /**
     * Method use to get count of image what we need 
     * @return
     */
    private static int[] getCountImage(){
        int xImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Config.xSize/256);
        int yImageCount = (int) Math.ceil(Config.ySize/256);
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get count of tiles
     * @return
     */
    private static int[] countImage(){
        int[] imageCount = getCountImage();
        int xImageCount = imageCount[0];
        int yImageCount = imageCount[1];
        if(xImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            xImageCount = xImageCount + 2;
        }
        if(yImageCount-1 %2 != 0){
            yImageCount = yImageCount + 2;
        }
        return  new int[] {xImageCount, yImageCount};
    }
    /**
     * Method use to get tiles 
     * @param lat
     * @param lon
     * @return
     */
    private static  ArrayList<BusStop2> getTiles(double lat, double lon ){
        int [] numberTile = TestURLImage.getMapByGeographicalCoordinates(lat, lon, Config.mapZoom);
        int a1 = 1;
        int a2 = 1;
        int a3 = 1;
        int a4 = 1;
        int [] countImage = countImage();
        int []x = new int [countImage[0]];
        int []y = new int [countImage[1]];
        x[0] = numberTile[0];
        y[0] = numberTile[1];
          for (int i = 1; i<x.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]+(a1);
                  a1++;
              }
              else{
                  x[i] = numberTile[0]-(a2);
                  a2++;
              }
          }

          for (int i = 1; i<y.length; i++){
              if(i%2==0){enter code here
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]+(a3);
                  a3++;
              }
              else{
                  y[i] = numberTile[1]-(a4);
                  a4++;
              }
          }

          for(int i = 0 ; i<x.length ; i++){
              for (int j = 0 ;j<y.length ; j++ ){
                  list.add(new BusStop2(x[i], y[j], x[0] - x[i], y[0]-y[j]));           
              }
          }
        return list;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     * @return
     */
    private static ArrayList<PositionTilesAndURLPaths> getImgPositionAndURLsPath(ArrayList<BusStop2> list){

        for(BusStop2 bus : list){
            positionTilesAndURLPathsList.add(new PositionTilesAndURLPaths(256*bus.getX(), 256*bus.getY(), Config.mapPath + "/" + bus.getA() + "/" + bus.getB() + ".png"));
        }
        return positionTilesAndURLPathsList;

    }
}
```

But I have to wait 10 seconds for the screen and it is too long. How could I speed up the process?

Comment: where do you loose time, how big are the images, is online access involved?

Comment: @thst a img is 256x256 i want to paint for whole screen , and i have 50 imgages, a images i get from a server . in first option i see how one picture draw and anather ,,,, i want to show frame with a picture –

Comment: your title is inappropriate, you dont know how to explain what you want, and images take long to load - so go figure